# How to ssh and then run commands?

Tags: bash

```
ssh -i dummy.pem ubuntu@server find /home/ubuntu/ -type f -print0 | 
xargs -0 stat --format '%Z' | sort -nr | cut -d: -f2- | head -1

stat: missing operand
Try `stat --help' for more information.
```

How can I ssh into a server, then grab the most recently modified time of a file in a directory recursively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use quote marks:
`ssh -i dummy.pem ubuntu@server 'find /home/ubuntu/ -type f -print0 | 
xargs -0 stat --format '%Z' | sort -nr | cut -d: -f2- | head -1'`

Answer (score 0):

you have to quote the command. Alternatively, you can use `<<`

```
ssh -i ... <<EOF
find /home...
EOF
```